# Setting IEEE FPE halting mode for OpenMP threads

Tags: fortran, language-lawyer, openmp, floating-point-exceptions

Consider the following Fortran + OpenMP program.

```
    use ieee_exceptions 
    
    implicit none
    
    integer, parameter :: n = 100
    real :: nom(n)
    integer :: denom(n)
    
    logical :: saved_fpe_mode(size(ieee_all))
    integer :: i
    
    nom = 1
    denom = 0
    
    call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_overflow, .true.)
    call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_invalid, .true.)
    call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_divide_by_zero, .true.)
    
    !$omp parallel
    print *,"hello from a thread"
    !$omp end parallel
    
    call ieee_get_halting_mode(ieee_all, saved_fpe_mode)
    call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_all, .false.)

    !$omp parallel do
    do i = 1, n
      nom(i) = nom(i) / denom(i)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do

    
    nom = min(max(0., nom), 1.)
    
    !$omp parallel
    call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_all, saved_fpe_mode)
    !$omp end parallel
    
    print *, nom
end
```

Is this code conforming to the joint combination of the Fortran standard and the OpenMP specifications? If yes, is this code supposed to halt or not when executed with multiple threads?

Comment: I asked a similar question at https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/should-this-openmp-code-halt-due-to-a-fpe/6710 but without an answer. If some answer does appear there with content you may want to write as well, don't hesitate to post an answer here and reference other answers if necessary.

Comment: I don't know what the combined standards say about this case, but it appears to be a bug in GCC.  Compiling the code with `-g` shows the FPE is occurring in `gcc/libgomp/team.c` at line 129.  Simple debugging shows this is the 2nd thread, so I suspect the manipulation of the FPU is not properly handle.

Comment: @steve Interesting. I get a normal FPE on line 28 but the stacktrace goes deeper and I likely lack the libgomp debug symbols. I previously also had some problems with Intel, but that happened when I used some compiler flags. The code shown in the question actually does not halt with Intel any more.

Comment: There could be a difference due to the OS.  I'm using FreeBSD on an AMD64 system with 2 cores.  libgomp sits on top of pthreads.  When ligomp is initialized I would assume that each thread inherits the state of the FPU.  It seems in my quick test that thread 1 (main parent thread?) initializes the FPU and thread 2 uses the default OS state for the FPU.  At least 2 gfortran developers are paid to work on OpenMP.  This looks like a candidate for a bug report (and yes, I know bugs reports can appear to go into a blackhole).

Comment: In the LLVM OpenMP runtime, when running on X86 and X86_64 processors, the floating point state of the initial thread is propagated to the child threads on entering a parallel region (unless explicitly disabled by setting the KMP_INHERIT_FP_CONTROL envirable to false). On other architectures this propagation does not seem to occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
% gfcx -o z -fopenmp -g b.f90 && ./z
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
 hello from a thread
Floating exception (core dumped)

% gdb131 ./z z.core
...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./z...
[New LWP 842524]
[New LWP 570543]
[New LWP 842525]
[New LWP 842526]
[New LWP 842527]
[New LWP 842528]
[New LWP 842529]
[New LWP 842530]

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/842524' in core file.

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for [vdso].
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
Core was generated by `./z'.
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/842524' in core file.
#0  0x0000000000400f64 in MAIN__::MAIN__._omp_fn.1 () at b.f90:28
28            nom(i) = nom(i) / denom(i)
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 842524)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400f64 in MAIN__::MAIN__._omp_fn.1 () at b.f90:28
#1  0x000000024210501e in gomp_thread_start (xdata=<optimized out>)
    at ../../../gccx/libgomp/team.c:129
#2  0x0000000244b38a75 in thread_start (curthread=0x1676c0612700)
    at /usr/src/lib/libthr/thread/thr_create.c:290
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

If the code is modified to

```
    !$omp parallel
    call ieee_get_halting_mode(ieee_all, saved_fpe_mode)
    call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_all, .false.)
    print *,"hello from a thread"
    !$omp end parallel
```

It compiles and executes.  So, setting the fpu state seems to be
thread specific.  Probably still worth a bug report.